# are blue ray disks the cheapest storage medium per Gb?

Tags: storage, blu-ray

The question is as simple as that really. Are bluray disks the cheapest storage medium per gb?

I am recording video which is using about 32gb per day.  So a month of that would be almost 1Tb. A year around 12tb.

I want to store at last a years worth with the possibility of more if needed.  To me it seems that cheap bluray disks world be the  cheapest solution.

But I wanted to get this confirmed.

Comment: No, LTO tapes are cheaper if you have very large volume (because the drive is expensive). Another hidden cost of Blu-ray is the very slow burning speed. However, in your case, blu-ray is the most economical solution as your volume is not big enough.

Comment: Looks like LTO tapes + drive only become cheaper than Blu-Ray disks + drives if I want to store 7+ years of 12Tb a year.  For 1 year of 12Tb using LTO will cost me around 770GBP, but the Blu-ray solution will cost 250GBP.  2 years of LTO will cost 870GBP and 2 years of Blu-ray will cost 440GBP.

Comment: Yeah, one major advantage of LTO is that you can reliably re-use the tapes, which is good for backups that only needs to be available for a few months. But I guess that is not relevant to your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something to keep in mind:

A quick check of media prices shows BD-R disks for around $1 each--4 cents per GB.

Hard drives are easier to get a good measure of the price as pricewatch tracks them--2tb for $90.  That's 4.5 cents per GB.

The drives are reusable, the disks are not.  In either case you need some sort of redundancy anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No, BluRay isn't the cheapest; tape is. M-Disc would be a better choice than BluRay.

A 10TB **hard drive** is less than 4¢ per GB, and has a reasonably fast access speed; also to be considered is ease of software backup and disk swapping. A 10TB HD >= 80 BDXLs, **if** you could write one disk in two hours (and come back to swap, label, put away; without error) that's a weeks work (24 hours/day).

It's much easier to install a drive, make a backup, uninstall the drive, and place it in a safe; than to swap all those disks. The write and read speeds are also much better, along with the convenience of having an entire backup on one disk, rather than having to figure out which set of BluRays holds the revision of the backup you wish to restore (or data you want to compare).

Huge capacity tape is also used for large capacity, but while the tape is relatively inexpensive the drives are not; small tapes (cheaper drives) lead to more swapping.

Media cost isn't the only cost. There's drive cost, convenience (time / effort), longevity (of drive and media, along with the format Standard) software availability / variety - all to be considered for the total cost.

Comment: Keep in mind that this question was asked in 2012. OP also had rather specific requirements.

Comment: @DanielB, true but the OP was active less than a month ago, and this answer serves the community and not one person. It answers the question being asked. The same question asked again could be a duplicate to this question, why not have a new answer.